# pylint \ flake8 plugins won't run from pyBuilder

Tags: plugins, pylint, flake8, pybuilder

No linter plugins seem to run from my pyBuild run.
I can use either

```
use_plugin("python.distutils")
```

or

```
use_plugin("python.flake8")
```

but when the pyBuilder run is finished, it says:
 Tasks: prepare [2073 ms] compile_sources [0 ms] run_unit_tests [504 ms] package [460 ms] run_integration_tests [0 ms] **verify [0 ms
]** publish [2164 ms]

Full build.py file:

```
from pybuilder.core import use_plugin, init

use_plugin("python.core")
use_plugin("python.pylint")
use_plugin("python.install_dependencies")
use_plugin("pypi:pybuilder_pytest")
use_plugin("pypi:pybuilder_pylint_extended")
#use_plugin("pypi:pybuilder_pytest_coverage")
use_plugin("python.distutils")

default_task = "publish"

@init
def initialize(project):
    project.author = "DellEMC"
    project.name = "RPCenter"
    project.set_property('dir_source_main_python', '..\..\services')
    project.get_property("pytest_extra_args").append("-x")
    project.set_property('dir_source_pytest_python', '..\..\services')
    #project.set_property('pytest_coverage_break_build_threshold', 75)
    project.set_property('pylint_options', '["--rcfile=pylintrc.txt", "--reports=n", "../../services"]')
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered exactly same problem and reached `pybuilder` issue tracker for help in [issue #652](https://github.com/pybuilder/pybuilder/issues/652).

As it has been [answered](https://github.com/pybuilder/pybuilder/issues/652#issuecomment-557755076) I quote

> Flake8 works quite well. It is however is registered as an analyze task which is not executed by default

So just run your build with a command that enables `analyze` tasks and yout `flake8` linting will be executed, as follows:

```
$ pyb analyze -vvv
PyBuilder version 0.11.17
Build started at 2019-11-23 13:22:04
------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  Building pybflake8 version 1.0.dev0
[INFO]  Executing build in /Users/marekyggdrasil/projects/pybflake8
[INFO]  Going to execute task analyze
[INFO]  Executing flake8 on project sources.
[WARN]  flake8: src/main/python/run.py:2:121: E501 line too long (345 > 120 characters)
------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILED - flake8 found 1 warning(s)
------------------------------------------------------------
Build finished at 2019-11-23 13:22:06
Build took 1 seconds (1627 ms)
```